# How to add a URL as a QGIS Favorite in browser

Tags: qgis, geojson, qgis-browser

I have GeoJSON/TopoJSON data stored in the cloud (on my S3 bucket).

Currently I have to instruct users to use the entire URL to add a JSON file to a project.

I would like to save the main portion of the URL as a favorite, so I can instruct users to use only the actual JSON file name. The "favorites" in the Browser Panel only accept paths to local data layers.

Is there a way in QGIS to save a URL as a favorite in the Browser Panel?